# Neo4j Style Rule New Line

Tags: styles, neo4j

Using Neo4j in the data browser the property text is displaying horizontally.  
In the style rules how can I modify this to display vertically?
In other words I want each property to display one line at a time like this:

"joe",

"dog"

As opposed to this:

"joe", "dog" 

Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a semicolon.
e.g. {name};{pet}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can set line breaks. Please raise an enhancement request in the issue tracker?

Comment: Hi Peter,  thank you for your response.  I have seen an example of this already in github.  Not sure which one I will go back and take a look.  Not sure if using third party tool.  Thank you